# How can I manage my RAM on a Nexus 5X?

Tags: ram, nexus-5x

I recently switched from a Samsung GS4 to a Nexus 5X. With my Samsung phone it was easy to clear out my RAM. I did it throughout the day to keep my phone running smoothly.

With my Nexus 5X, I can't figure out how to do it. Under settings, it tells me the average RAM usage (1.7GB) and which apps are using it but not how to free up RAM. When I google it, all the results suggest I clear the cache which is not the same as RAM. I even installed an app, Greenify, to try and help free up RAM but I couldn't get my phone to allow the app the permissions needed in order to force stop and control apps running in the background. I'm using Android 7.1.1. I regularly clear open applications but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You usually don't need to manage the RAM on a modern phone unless the manufacturer has a flawed configuration for the internal RAM management built into Android. The fact that there isn't even a built in way to easily clean RAM backs this up. If you *really* need to manage the RAM manually, start by rooting your device to be able to stop system processes and resilient services.

Comment: I play Pokemon GO and that uses a lot of RAM. I'd really like to close background stuff so that I can switch between Pokemon and another app without it restarting every time. I don't want to root my phone.

Comment: Oh, I see. You may want to add this information to your question. I don't know much (or anything) about the RAM management present on the Nexus 5X but I'm pretty sure you will find an answer soon.

Comment: I'd say that 2GB RAM on the 5X is simply not enough, especially with the OS itself eating a considerable portion of that up.